# axios returns 406 on redirect

Tags: node.js, axios

My node.js server code is like this

```
const doRedirect = (req, res) {
    return res.redirect('some url here');
}

app.post('/some_path', doRedirect);
```

in my test,

```
const loginOptions = (body, cookie) => {
    return {
        url: 'http://localhost/some_path',
        data: body,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Cookie: cookie,
            'User-Agent': getUserAgent()
        },
    };
};

it('my redirect test', async () => {
    const some_tests = loginOptions({}, '123'); 
    try {
        const res = await axios(some_request);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('why hit here ?');
    }
}
```

When i test redirect manually in local node server, it does the redirect just fine.

But to my surprise, the res.status is 406, why is this ?

Comment: Did you log `e`? What is `some_request`? I guess, further details are needed.

Comment: actually it's not exception but 406 status, updated the original post

Comment: Your route shows a POST, but your `await axios(some_request);` is a GET so those two will never match each other.  Can you show us the real code here, not just tiny little snippets of fake code?  Also, obviously `res.redirect()` doesn't send a 406 unless you have a coding error somewhere so we need to see the REAL code, REAL urls, etc... in order to have a chance at helping.

Comment: updated, it's a POST

Comment: It's clearly still fake code.  In `await axios(some_request)`, `some_request` is not defined anywhere.  Sorry, but I'm not going to chase my tail trying to debug code that isn't the real code.

Comment: Do you know if the code even gets to your `doRedirect()` function on the server?  Your job is to find out who's making the 406 status and where its coming from.  That will be the best hint as to what is wrong.

Comment: If i start the local node.js server and send from curl, it works as expected with redirect. It's this test code using axios returns 406. No worries, you have been helping, thx !